# Java: Subarrays and Binary search algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search, arrays

I must create a program that searches for an int in arr1 by a binary search algorithm and return -1 if the int isn't found. I'm having trouble with creating subarrays. It works at the moment without them but I've only a workaround for whenever the int is greater than start.

```
public class Question8p2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr1 = {2,45,234,567,876,900,976,999};
        int start = arr1.length / 2;
        int searchNum = 900;
        arraySearch(start, searchNum, arr1);
        System.out.println(arraySearch(start, searchNum, arr1));
    }

    public static int arraySearch(int start, int searchNum, int [] arr1){
        if (arr1[start] == searchNum){
            return start;
        }

        if (arr1[start] < searchNum){
            start = start + 1;
        }

        if (arr1[start] > searchNum){
            start = start / 2;
        }

        if (start == arr1[0] || start == arr1.length){
            return -1;
        }

        return arraySearch(start, searchNum, arr1);
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont understand your problem. what do you mean by `I'm having trouble with creating subarrays.`

Comment: This is not binary search. When the target lies in the right half of the array, you only increment the `start` by one. You need start and end in your recursive method.

Comment: Take look at http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/BinarySearch.java.html for binary search

Comment: http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/CS3343/recursion/binsearch.html

Comment: And you are assuming the given array is already sorted. if the array is not sorted binary search wont work. Do sort first

Comment: @Mani That has no sense. You should assume the array is already sorted for binary search, if you'd sort everytime - you end up worse than linear search.

Comment: @amit Agreed. it is very good assumption the input array is already sorted. but i thought , this is kind of homework/practice and may be OP may not aware on this. And i did not say do Sort with in binary search. Do sort before start binary search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First to answer your question - you can create a sub-array by using [`Arrays.copyOfRange(array,from,to)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)..

**However,** this is NOT what you want to do. Creating a subarray this way is `O(n)` (recall that it is a copy..), and you don't want to do it.

Instead, use arguments in your method, `start` and `end` - that indicate the range your binary search is looking for now.

Also note that increasing by 1 when the element is not found is not binary search, instead you need to design your algorithm that it will always 'jump' by half of the remaining array - and not by a constant size.

According to this, your method signature will be something like:

```
public static int arraySearch( int [] arr1, int start, int end, int searchNumber){ ... }
```

You will then set a `mid` element: `int mid = start + (end - start)/2;`

And you will check if the required number is bigger than `arr1[mid]` or not.

If it is, you will recurse with `arraySearch(arr1,mid+1,end,searchNumber)`, and if it is smaller you will recurse with `arraySearch(arr1,start,mid,searchNumber)`

Hope that clarifies how your binary search should be implemented.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

The very best way to perform that search in Java is this:

```
Arrays.binarySearch(arr1, start, arr1.length, searchNum);
```

However, since a reinventing-the-wheel is required for the assignment, you can't just use that. But there are a number of hints you can take from [`Arrays.binarySearch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5b%5d,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to help design your program.

One of the main obstacles you are facing here is the method signature you are using:

```
public static int arraySearch(int start, int searchNum, int [] arr1)
```

If you were to pattern your method signature off that used by the `Arrays.binarySearch` method, the task becomes much easier. So you should be implementing something that also allows an end index to be specified. I would also change the argument order to match `Arrays.binarySearch`, and even call it `binarySearch`:

```
public static int binarySearch(int [] a, int fromIdx, int toIdx, int key)
```

So you should do something like this.

```
public static int binarySearch(int [] a, int fromIdx, int toIdx, int key){
    if(fromIdx == toIdx) return -1;

    int pivotIdx = (fromIdx + toIdx)/2;

    if(a[pivotIdx] < key) return binarySearch(a, fromIdx, pivotIdx, key);
    if(a[pivotIdx] == key) return pivotIdx;
    if(a[pivotIdx] > key) return binarySearch(a, pivotIdx, toIdx, key);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So in your recursive call you will need to only pass an array half the length of the array. You could create a new array with only the first or second half of your array:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29

The other option is to use max and min integers to mark what section of the array you are looking at. If your searchNum is less than the value your are looking at, set max to your start variable. If search Num less than the number you are looking at, set min to start. 
At the beginning your method, if your current start is <=max or >= min return -1 because you would be searching where you had already looked before therefore the number you are looking for isn't in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- Add `end` to your method call as @anonymous suggested.
- At each recursive call of `ArraySearch`, make the values of `start` and `end` such that
  `arr1[start] < searchNum < arr1[end]`
- And at each recursive call, make the distance between `start` and `end` half (roughly) of what it was on the previous call.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like as mentioned below:

```
    private int BinarySearch(int[] array, int low, int high, int number)
    {

        // First get the middle index using high and low index 
        int medium = (high + low) / 2;

        // Check if the number you are looking is same as the one at middle index?
        // If that is the case, just return the middle index
        if (array[medium] == number)
        {
           return medium;
        }
        else
        {
            // if the number is not found in previous condition resume the operation. 

            // Check if number is greater than the middle index number 
            if (array[medium] < number)
            {
               // call the search operation by replacing your low index with middle + 1
               return  BinarySearch(array, medium + 1, high, number);
            }
            else
            {
               // Here number is less than the middle index number 
               // call the search operation by replacing your high index with middle-1 
               return  BinarySearch(array, low, medium - 1, number);
            }
        }
    }
```